# when I require intro.js in my angular2 project with webpack manager,it can start but without css

Tags: css, angular, webpack, require

when I require intro.js in my angular2 project with webpack manager,it can start but without css.
it is my code:

```
 var introJS=require('intro.js');
@Component({
  selector: 'intro',
  styles:[require('./source/introjs.css')],
  template: require('./intro.html'),
})

export class Intro implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("intro component,start。。。。。");
  }

  startIntro(info){
    introJS.introJs().start();
    console.log(info);
  }
```

and it is my page view when I click start to show intro:

[without css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTfmD.png)

but I have tested already,the css is work when I use the css class in html page.
Sorry,I am a new one in angular2 and webpack.
I think the problem is in css load in,I have no idea about it .Thank you everyone.

Comment: While we don't expect a perfect English, SO if for English speaking people. Try getting a friend to translate for  you (or edit your question).

Comment: Make sure the relative address to `.css` file is correct. the rest seem ok to me.

Comment: OK,thank you.In fact，I had tried many times.

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed that the CSS file is not work.Because the new div named intro-tooltip is under all tag.You know the page is assembled by many components,so the now div is not match the css file in the intro component.When I move css file in index.html.It is work.But it is not a component already.